# How to Migrate to WKWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, ios8, wkwebview

I'm trying to understand how to make use of the new WKWebView in iOS8, can't find much information. I've read:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/why-ios-8s-wkwebview-is-a-big-deal-for-hybrid-development/
http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/

But how does this affect existing apps? Will an ordinary UiWebView get the speedup from the nitro java script engine or do we need to make changes? How do we deal with backwards compatibility?

All the code and examples I can find are using swift, will this be mandatory?

Thankful for any help on this matter!

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://floatlearning.com/2014/12/one-webview-to-rule-them-all/

Comment: http://blog.initlabs.com/post/100113463211/wkwebview-vs-uiwebview

Comment: Look onto my answer to add it as a subview in swift 3.0 http://stackoverflow.com/a/41205568/2356808

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793618/ios-wkwebview-vs-uiwebview

Answer (score 68):

`UIWebView` will still continue to work with existing apps. `WKWebView` is available starting from `iOS8`, only `WKWebView` has a Nitro JavaScript engine.

To take advantage of this faster JavaScript engine in older apps you have to make code changes to use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. For `iOS7` and older, you have to continue to use `UIWebView`, so you may have to check for `iOS8` and then apply `WKWebView` methods / delegate methods and fallback to `UIWebView` methods for `iOS7` and older. Also there is no Interface Builder component for `WKWebView` (yet), so you have to programmatically implement `WKWebView`.

You can implement `WKWebView` in Objective-C, here is simple example to initiate a `WKWebView`:

```c
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

`WKWebView` rendering performance is noticeable in WebGL games and something that runs complex JavaScript algorithms, if you are using webview to load a simple html or website, you can continue to use `UIWebView`.

Here is a test [app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id928647773?mt=8&at=10ltWQ) that can used to open any website using either `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` and you can compare performance, and then decide on upgrading your app to use `WKWebView`:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id928647773?mt=8&at=10ltWQ

[image]

Comment: Also consider this, using a technique to use WKWebView on iOS 8 and fallback to UIWebView on iOS 7 might ran into AppStore validation issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897123/including-webkit-framework-for-ios8-fails-validation

Comment: Just a note: needs use `NSAppTransportSecurity` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist` to works.

Comment: It is now impossible to use UIWebView, you can't push an app on the store which use it

Answer (score 55):

Here is how I transitioned from **UIWebView** to **WKWebView**.

> Note: There is no property like UIWebView that you can drag onto your
>   storyboard, you have to do it programatically.

Make sure you import **WebKit/WebKit.h** into your header file.

This is my header file:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productURL;

@end
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.productURL = @"http://www.URL YOU WANT TO VIEW GOES HERE";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.productURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: how to load a local file? I tried but nothing appeared on the page. Also what are the delegate methods like UIWebview. For example: didloadRequest

Comment: Just a note: needs use `NSAppTransportSecurity` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist` to works.

Comment: I copied your above code.  I tried several URLs which normally work in browser.  Nothing shows in the view.  What could be missing?

Answer (score 21):

***Step : 1*** Import `webkit` in `ViewController.swift`

```
import WebKit
```

***Step : 2*** Declare variable of webView.

```
var webView : WKWebView!
```

***Step : 3*** Adding Delegate of `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate{
```

***Step : 4*** Adding code in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
let myBlog = "https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/"
let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

// init and load request in webview.
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.loadRequest(request)
self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(webView)
```

***Step : 5*** Edit the `info.plist` adding

```
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>google.com</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: how to save cookie in wekwebview

Comment: Just a note: needs use `NSAppTransportSecurity` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist` to works.

Comment: @KiritModi how to save cookie in wkwebview , i am facing logout issue ( session expired ) , kindly comment

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari : see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview

Comment: @kirtimali you can not read http only cookie from wkwebview upto ios 10. But in ios 11 apple has introduce new API to read cookie from wkwebview https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore?changes=latest_minor

Answer (score 10):

Swift is not a requirement, everything works fine with Objective-C. UIWebView will continue to be supported, so there is no rush to migrate if you want to take your time. However, it will not get the javascript and scrolling performance enhancements of WKWebView.

For backwards compatibility, I have two properties for my view controller: a UIWebView and a WKWebView. I use the WKWebview only if the class exists:

```
if ([WKWebView class]) {
    // do new webview stuff
} else {
    // do old webview stuff
}
```

Whereas I used to have a UIWebViewDelegate, I also made it a WKNavigationDelegate and created the necessary methods.

Comment: Using [WKWebView class] to do runtime check is a very good point,  much better than checking iOS version number.

Comment: FYI can you mentioned from which version wkwebview not available ? seems to be available from ios 8 onwards so dont need to add this check and redundant code.

Answer (score 8):

WkWebView is much faster and reliable than UIWebview according to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/). 
Here, I posted my WkWebViewController.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebPageViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate,WKNavigationDelegate{

    var webView: WKWebView?
    var webUrl="http://www.nike.com"

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false

    }
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        /* Create our preferences on how the web page should be loaded */
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false

        /* Create a configuration for our preferences */
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences

        /* Now instantiate the web view */
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

        if let theWebView = webView{
            /* Load a web page into our web view */
            let url = NSURL(string: self.webUrl)
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            theWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
            theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
            view.addSubview(theWebView)

        }


    }
    /* Start the network activity indicator when the web view is loading */
    func webView(webView: WKWebView,didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    /* Stop the network activity indicator when the loading finishes */
    func webView(webView: WKWebView,didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView,
        decidePolicyForNavigationResponse navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)){
            //print(navigationResponse.response.MIMEType)
            decisionHandler(.Allow)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

WKWebView using Swift in iOS 8..

The whole ViewController.swift file now looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.kinderas.com/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some design patterns, you can mix UIWebView and WKWebView.
The key point is to design a unique browser interface.
But you should pay more attention to your app's current functionality,
for example: if your app using NSURLProtocol to enhance network ability, using WKWebView you have no chance to do the same thing. Because NSURLProtocol only effects the current process, and WKWebView using  muliti-process architecture, the networking staff is in a seperate process.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WKWebView, which is available as of iOS8 in Framework 'WebKit' to get the speedup.
If you need backwards compatibility, you have to use UIWebView for iOS7 and older.

I set up a little code to provide the UIViewController frame for the new WKWebView. It can be installed via cocoapods. Have a look here:

[`STKWebKitViewController on github`](https://github.com/sticksen/STKWebKitViewController)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
    let webView = WKWebView()   // Set Frame as per requirment, I am leaving it for you
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    view.addSubview(webView)
```