# WKWebView is not displaying content in custom UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

In my storyboard I have something like a individual navigation bar (three buttons in a row) and below this navbar there should be a WKWebView.

So I create a UIView called webViewSize and implement the WKWebView.

```
 var webView: WKWebView!
 @IBOutlet weak var webViewSize: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webViewSize = self.webView

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if self.url.characters.count > 0 {
            if let url = NSURL(string: self.url) {
                self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
                self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
            }
        }
    } 
  }
```

After a few seconds the WK delegate didFinishNavigation is called, but nothing is shown.
When I change `self.webViewSize = self.webView` to `self.view = self.webView` everything works fine.

I searched a lot to handle this. I worked with subviews, repeat the line `self.webViewSize = self.webView` in didFinishNavigation, but nothing work.

What's my mistake?

PS: I know it's Swift 2, but it's an old(er) project. Atm I have to handle this. It will be convert in time.

Comment: look onto it http://stackoverflow.com/a/41205568/2356808

Comment: Thanks for that, worked for me. I didn't find... sorry! 
Difference to my solution: I didn't use the programmatically constraints in this link. A normal containerView is working for me.

Comment: Glad that it helped